# Obtaining all solutions of a linear equation by weighted generalized inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, pseudoinverse, weighted-least-squares

Consider a linear equation
$$
Ax=b,\quad b\in\operatorname{col}(A).
$$
The vector $b$ lies in the column space of $A$ so the solution of this linear equation exists.

It is known that any solution has the form
$$
x = A^\dagger b + (I-A^\dagger A)h
$$
for arbitrary $h$, where $A^\dagger b$ is the least-square solution of $Ax=b$ (as a specific solution), and $(I-A^\dagger A)$ has the same null space with $A$.

Now, consider a **weighted** least-square problem:
$$
\min_{Ax=b} x^\top Rx,
$$
where $R$ is positive definite. The solution is
$$
x = R^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(AR^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^\dagger b.
$$

My question is, by taking arbitrary positive definite matrices $R$, is it possible to obtain **all** solutions of $Ax=b$, just like taking arbitrary $h$ to obtain all solutions by $x = A^\dagger b + (I-A^\dagger A)h$?